# How to specify environment when using the graph api (beta) to access D365 Business Central data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, dynamics-business-central

This Microsoft document details how you can use the Graph API beta to access Business Central data:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/dynamics-companies-get?view=graph-rest-beta

As an example, to get a list of companies the doco provides this path:-

`..../financials/companies`

Obvious ommission here is any reference to the environment eg Sandbox, Production etc.

And, predictably, when I try it I get:-

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "NoEnvironment",
        "message": "Environment does not exist.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-08-11T01:24:51",
            "request-id": "3a946cdd-f370-455d-8309-367fd8ccc588",
            "client-request-id": "3a946cdd-f370-455d-8309-367fd8ccc588"
        }
    }
}
```

How do you specify the environment? Don't see this anywhere in the doco.

I am successfully authenticating and getting data from other Graph sources eg Users.

Comment: Can you please check the permissions are there which are required to access the API, please refer this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/dynamics-companies-get?view=graph-rest-beta#permissions

Comment: Yes permissions have been granted as per the documentation.  Error does not appear to be permissions related.  If Graph provides access to Business Central and you can have multiple Business Central environments (eg Production, Sandbox etc) there must be somewhere either in the App Registration or the Authentication or the Request that you need to specify the environment you are wanting to access.